# error while putting correct git commit commands

Tags: git, git-commit

Can you outline why I am receiving this message in git commit despite correct codes. I have tried all the alternatives and even restarting it again but no positive responses.
Here's the error https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr9zd.png

Answer (score 0):

If there are un-staged files, you should put

`git commit -am “first commit”`

You need to fist add the un-staged files which `-a` in the command does. `m` is just for the commit message.

If all the modified files are staged, you can give this command

`git commit -m “first commit”` //This will do. Notice the space between commit and -m (`m` is for commit message )

Answer (score -1):

There is no such git command as `commit-m`. Maybe you got that from someone who had it installed as a local command alias?

Comment: Looks more like a typo for `git commit -m ...`.